# Class constructor won't work in a different file?

Tags: c++, operating-system

So We're making an OS simulation for a class project. Ours has a class called "PCB" (short for process control block) which naturally holds all the information a process needs to run properly. I'm trying to dynamically instantiate PCBs but I've run into an issue. For some reason it keeps saying that my argument list is wrong for the constructor even though it appears to be. I am calling this function from Shell.cpp, the declaration of the class is in PCB.h and PCB.cpp, and both of these are seperate from main.

Here's the class in PCB.h:

```
class PCB {
private:
    int identifier; //Unique identifier for each process
    int processSize; //how much memory is required to run
    ProcessState state; //State of the process
    int priority; //Priority level relative to other processes
    int programCounter; //Address of the next instruction in the program     to be executed
    int contextdata; //data that are present in registers in the processor while its executing
    int io; //work on, includes outstanding IO requires, devices, list of files in use, etc
    AccountingInfo info;
public:
    PCB(int, int, int, time_t);
    ~PCB();
        void test(); //test method to print info
    void assignState(ProcessState state); //method to assign a state to a process
    ProcessState returnState(); //method to return the current state of a process
    int returnId();//method to return the process's ID
    bool checkMem();//method to see if there is enough memory available
    void clearMem();//method to free memory
};
```

Here's the constructor definition in PCB.cpp:

```
PCB::PCB(int id, int size, int pLevel, time_t programTime){

    this->identifier = id; //provide the process id
    this->processSize = size; // provides the required size in memory
    this->state = start; //set the state of all new processes to start
    this->priority = pLevel; //set the priority level
    this->programCounter = 0; //temp
    this->contextdata = 0; //temp
    this->io = 0; //temp
    this->info.timeLeft = programTime; //sets the amount of time the program requires to run
    this->info.timeSlice = TIMESLICE; //sets the value of a timeslice

}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in Shell.cpp:

```
void initializePCB() {
    tempPCB = new PCB(1, 2, 3, 4);
    //tempPCB->assignState(new);
    //tempPCB->

}
```

PCB.h is included in Shell.cpp.

EDIT: It turns out that for some reason it wants me to pass only 3 arguments into the PCB constructor. Even when I do that, the linker comes up with this error:

```
1>Shell.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall PCB::PCB(int,int,__int64)" (??0PCB@@QAE@HH_J@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl initializePCB(void)" (?initializePCB@@YAXXZ)
```

How can I initialize this class?

Comment: How are you compiling Shell.cpp?

Comment: I suspect you're including a different PCB.h file to the one you think you're including.

Comment: Double-check you project - click on PCB.h in Solution Explorer and go to Properties for this file. Is it _really_ the PCB.h you need ? We all suspect you have multiple copies of PCB.h here and there.

Comment: Adding more to @immibis's comment: in _Shell.cpp_ (or as a matter of fact in any _.h_/_.cpp_ files in your project) are you including `"PCB.h"` and not `<PCB.h>`? Based on the linker's error message I assume you use _Visual Studio_; in the IDE you can right click on the filename of the `#include` directive _Open document ..._ and check if it's yours (if not, check its _Properties_ to get its full path).

Comment: Yeah you guys were right. Looks like I got my directories mixed up when working with git. It's very strange that it would show a different file from what it was compiling when I double click on it in the solution explorer. Thanks for the help! If anyone wants credit for an answer Just post one up and I'll close it.